# Apache responding to telnet http requests but not browser

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

Running Apache on CentOS:

- the server **does not** respond to **remote http requests** made via **curl or a web browser** (the connection is made, the request is sent, but it juste times out after a while),
- the server **does** respond to **remote http requests** made via **telnet**,
- weirdly, it **does** respond to **local curl http requests**.

Remote telnet request:

```
$ telnet www.MYDOMAIN.com.cn 80                                                                                                                     
Trying XXX.XX.X.XX...
Connected to www.MYDOMAIN.com.cn.
Escape character is '^]'.

GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.39.0
Host: www.MYDOMAIN.com.cn
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 17 Jun 2015 23:21:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Jun 2015 19:31:35 GMT
ETag: "601a7-8-518bbbd2925bd"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 8
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Hello !
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Remote curl request:

```
$ curl -v http://www.MYDOMAIN.com.cn/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying XXX.XX.X.XX...
* Connected to www.MYDOMAIN.com.cn (XXX.XX.X.XX) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.39.0
> Host: www.MYDOMAIN.com.cn
> Accept: */*
>
```

Hence, it does not seem to be a firewall issue (iptables is configured to let incoming tcp traffic through on port 80, which it does since the remote telnet requests are answered).

I have been bashing my head all day with this one: all suggestions welcome.

**Edit:**

It seems to be a PMTUD issue. Here is the output of `iptables-save` after I tried fixing it (it still does not work):

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [29:2820]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6344:506105]
:INPUT ACCEPT [601:53242]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [29:2820]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [29:2820]
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu 
COMMIT
```

Comment: PMTU discovery problem? When you use telnet each line is send as a separate TCP packet, so the packets will be smaller. If you use an ordinary HTTP client, the request may very well start with a TCP packet containing a full MSS.

Comment: @kasperd: That makes sense. Any idea how to test that?

Comment: Look at the network traffic using tcpdump or wireshark. If it is an MTU issue you can expect to see the client repeatedly transmit the same TCP packet. But you will only see that packet when inspecting traffic on the client side. If you inspect the traffic on the server side instead, you will not see that packet. The server will see a handshake complete, and then it won't see another packet.

Comment: @kasperd: Indeed, the client seems to send the same packet over and over. Any idea how to resolve that issue?

Comment: Reduce the MSS from its current value to something lower. Usually using 1220 as the MSS will eliminate MTU problems. You can either do it by changing the `advmss` setting in the routing table on the server (but be careful not to lock yourself out by misconfiguring the network), or you can use iptables to clamp the MSS to 1220 on all incoming and outgoing SYN packets.

Comment: @kasperd: Thanks, I edited my post to include my iptables rules. I tried to use the `--clamp-mss-to-pmtu` option but it does not seem to work.

Comment: The name `--clamp-mss-to-pmtu` is slightly misleading because iptables doesn't know the exact PMTU. It only knows about two hops on the path. Instead you could try `--set-mss 1220` on SYN packets in both directions.

Comment: Your MSS rule is in the wrong chain. You need two MSS rules one has to be in either `PREROUTING` or `INPUT` the other has to be in either `OUTPUT` or `POSTROUTING`.

Comment: @kasperd: It seems the issue was resolved by the provider by fixing their network, and I believe it was indeed a PMTU discovery issue. Would you care to make it an answer so that I can validate it?

Comment: Or you can do it if kasperd don't, then you can mark your answer as valid.